# How can you create your own custom source map?

Tags: javascript, source-maps

Are there any tools which can easily make source maps for you? To be clear, I want to make a javascript file and be able to write psuedo code for my source map. I intend to teach program with source maps showing psuedo code.

Eg.

```
let $in = 5;
let $out = a;
while (b !== 0)
{
    $in--;
    $out++;
}
console.log($in + " - " + $out);
```

might be

```
   IN = 5
   OUT = IN
-> JUMP IF IN IS ZERO->|
|  DECREMENT IN        |
|  INCREMENT OUT       |
|<-JUMP                |
                     <-|
```

Answer (score -1):

normally i'd use `devtool: 'source-map'`